# Trying to get percentage of mobile users using Google Analytics API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get percentage of mobile users on a website using the Google Analytics API in PHP.

Per https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/common-queries, I am pretty sure I am using the right dimensions/metrics (below):

```
dimensions=ga:mobileDeviceInfo,ga:source
metrics=ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:sessionDuration
```

I get back an array of mobile devices (expected) but see no way to convert that into a percentage.

The first array element **(not set)** I assume is the **non-mobile traffic**, but the numbers simply **don't** add up ( non-mobile traffic / total number of sessions doesn't equal the % mobile in the Google Analytics dashboard).

Any ideas or examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using *ga:mobileDeviceInfo*, I would use *ga:deviceCategory*. This way you're able to see the number of sessions by *Desktop, Tablet, Mobile.* Does this match what you see in the interface?

```
dimensions=ga:deviceCategory
metrics=ga:sessions
```

Also bear in mind to make sure the date range/filters/segmentation of the API and the UI are the same.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed thanks! Not sure why Google doesn't make it more obvious..device categories is what people are most interested in..not device types!